# Display label on Polygons in google map using MapLabel in react

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, dictionary, label, polygon

I am using MapLabel to display Labels on polygons.

```
import MapLabel from 'googlemaps-v3-utility-library';

const mapLabel = new MapLabel({
   text: 'Polygon Label',
   position,
   map,
   fontSize: 20,
   align: 'left'
 });
mapLabel.set('position', position);
```

But I am getting an error Unable to resolve the path to module 'googlemaps-v3-utility-library'.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the module is in your package.json dependencies.
Something like this

```
{
    "dependencies":{
    googlemaps-v3-utility-library,
    ....
    },
    ....
}
```

If it is not present you have to install it with

```
npm i googlemaps-v3-utility-library
```